# Making OpenGL wait for OpenCL on OS X

Tags: macos, opengl, synchronization, opencl

I was wondering if it's possible to make OpenGL commands on OS X block on the completion of previous OpenCL commands, without blocking the host at all.

[Apple's](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/OpenCL_MacProgGuide/shareGroups/shareGroups.html) documentation [describes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/OpenCL_MacProgGuide/SynchronizingCLandGL/SynchronizingCLandGL.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008312-CH18-SW1) signaling a semaphore after (synchronously) executing an OpenCL kernel on another thread. However, I'm hoping instead to keep all OpenGL and OpenCL calls asynchronous and not having to stall host execution on a semaphore.

Going the other way (making OpenCL wait for OpenGL) is what the [cl_khr_gl_event](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/gl_event.html) OpenCL extension is for, and it seems to work great (except it's reverse of what I want).

The [ARB_cl_event](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/cl_event.txt) OpenGL extension seems to do what I want, but it doesn't seem to be present on Macs. :-(

I was thinking that maybe I could create a OpenGL sync object, link it to an OpenCL event, then somehow make OpenCL enqueue a task that would trigger the event, thereby triggering the sync object. I was thinking that I could then use glWaitSync to make GL pause. However, this approach won't work because there is no way to create a OpenGL sync event without inserting it into the command stream immediately.

Is there some way that I'm missing to do this on OS X without making the host block?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like clEnqueueAcquireGLObjects and clEnqueueReleaseGLObjects perform all the necessary synchronization. It seems that clCreateEventFromGLsyncKHR isn't necessary in this case.